# copy large data to GCS

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

I have 10001920 images.And their name is train_0, train_1, ....
I tried to copy them like

```py
!gsutil -m cp -r /content/train/* gs://{my_bucket_name}/data
```

And I failed b.c it was too long. So I decided to use wild card like

```py
!gsutil -m cp -r /content/train/train_1????.png gs://{my_bucket_name}/data
```

And I wanted to upload iterative way. After using 'for statement' to generate command line,

```py
for script in script_list:
    os.system(script)
```

And returns

```py
31512
```

I just wanna know how can I upload those huge files to GCS.
Please give me some ideas

Comment: "Nothing happened" really nothing? Not even an error? Did you check that script_list wasn't empty? It seems to me what you are trying should work.

Comment: Is there any console output?

Comment: it returns 32512, I'll edit my post

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `*` should be used. It's not used that way in the documentation. I'd just try:

`!gsutil -m cp -r ./content/train gs://{my_bucket_name}/data`

[This explains the failure number:](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/GlobalCommandLineOptions)

> Also, although most commands normally fail upon encountering an error when the -m flag is disabled, all commands continue to try all operations when -m is enabled with multiple threads or processes, and the number of failed operations (if any) are reported as an exception at the end of the command's execution.

Comment: Hi, appreciate for your suggestion. I'll try it. But in my opinion, there's too many files in train folder. So I would not work at this moment.